# Downloading a .NET DLL from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want my C#.NET program to go download my DLL from a table in SQL Server which I don't know what type of column I even need to keep a DLL in it, and then run that DLL.
How can I do this? What do I need on the C# side and what column type do I need in SQL Server side?

Comment: You can store it as varbinary just like you would any kind of document. And then to use that during run-time, you can look into Run-Time Dynamic Linking : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685090(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This would require your program know how to lid the full after its started which is possible just not trivial

Answer (score 1):

As a DLL is a binary object your best bet would be the varbinary(x) type, where x is the size of the column in bytes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms188362.aspx